# Regex server_name and root

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

So im trying to get my regex in nginx to work with my reviews

```
server {
        listen          80;
        listen          [::]:80;
        server_name     ~^(?<branch>\w+)\.review\.project\.company\.eu$;
        root            /ext/project.company.eu/review/$branch;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/$branch.review.project.company.eu_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/$branch.review.project.company.eu_access.log;
}
```

So it should resolve if I go to the subdomain `http://something.review.project.company.eu` though it just doesnt work.

Though my urls also have `-` (dashes) in it, so fx `http://my-new-branch.review.project.company.eu` should also resolve to the configuration.

I have cutted the location tag from the `server {}` configuration for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to define it strictly, why not just try to match other than dot?

```
server_name     ~^(?<branch>[^.]+)\.review\.project\.company\.eu$
```